# ASP MVC multiple dropdownlist search form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dynamic, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to perform a search with a form that has multiple dropdownlistfor to restrict the search values, the dropdownlist are filled thru a viewmodel.

view model: PesquisaHomeViewModel.cs

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; 
using MinisPT.Models;

namespace MinisPT.ViewModels {
     public class PesquisaHomeViewModel
     {
        public List<Marca> Marcas { get; set; }       
         public List<Modelo> Modelos { get; set; }
         public List<EstadoProduto> EstadosProdutos { get; set; }
     } 
}
```

this is part of the view with the form: Home/Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ResultadosPesquisa", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)                 
                <div id="coluna1">
                <div class="coluna1_titulo">Marca</div>
                <div class="coluna1_DropDownList">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Marcas, new SelectList(Model.Marcas, "MarcaNome", "MarcaNome"), String.Empty)
                </div>
                <div class="coluna1_titulo">Modelo</div>
                <div class="coluna1_DropDownList">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(md => md.Modelos, new SelectList(Model.Modelos, "ModeloNome", "ModeloNome"), String.Empty)
                </div>
                <div class="coluna1_titulo">Estado</div>
                <div class="coluna1_DropDownList">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.EstadosProdutos, new SelectList(Model.EstadosProdutos, "EstadoProdutoTipo", "EstadoProdutoTipo"), String.Empty)
                </div>
                <span>
                    <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="botaoPesquisa" />
                </span>                
           }
```

As you can see thru that submit, I call the index action of the "ResultadosPesquisa" controller, in that controller i use the parameters of the form and try to do the search against a model named "Anuncios"  (this means "Ads" in my language)

ResultadosPesquisaController.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using MinisPT.Models;
using MinisPT.ViewModels;

namespace MinisPT.Controllers
{
    public class ResultadosPesquisaController : Controller
    {
        MinisPTEntities db = new MinisPTEntities();

        //
        // GET: /ResultadosPesquisa/
        public ActionResult Index(string Marcas, string Modelos, string EstadosProdutos)
        {
            var query = from m in db.Anuncios.Include(a => a.Marca).Include(a => a.Modelo)
                        where m.Marca.MarcaNome == Marcas
                        where m.Modelo.ModeloNome == Modelos
                        where m.EstadoProduto.EstadoProdutoTipo == EstadosProdutos
                        select m;

            return View(query.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

wich calls the view ResultadosPesquisa/Index.cshtml were i'm supposed to display the results later:

```
@model IEnumerable<MinisPT.Models.Anuncio>

... (html stuff in here) 

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Marca
        </th>
        <th>
            Modelo
        </th>
        <th>
            Estado
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.Marca.MarcaNome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.Modelo.ModeloNome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.EstadoProduto.EstadoProdutoTipo)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**MY problem is ** the query on ResultadosPesquisaController only gets me results if i put values on ALL 3 dropdownlists, if i only select a value in one of the dropdowns nothing is returned, but i want to make all the dropdowns optional, how can i achive this?

I thought of one possible way, using LINQ Dynamic Query Library,

[using LINQ Dynamic Query Library by scott gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

That way i could construct the query on the first index action, with a bunch of if statements (not very elegant) and redirect to a second action where i would use the pre-builded query with dynamic LINQ and execute it.

If there's a more elegant way of acomplishing this please advise me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The way you have your Linq structured it is stacking like an `&&` operation. You need to change it to this:

```
var query = from m in db.Anuncios.Include(a => a.Marca).Include(a => a.Modelo)
            where m.Marca.MarcaNome == Marcas ||
                m.Modelo.ModeloNome == Modelos ||
                m.EstadoProduto.EstadoProdutoTipo == EstadosProdutos
            select m
```

This should return results from any of the selections.

**Edit:**
Based on your comments below, it might be better for you to stack them using the extension methods instead. Since this is going to a data context (my assumption based on `db.Anuncios`), these calls will be deferred until they are actually used.

```
var query = from m in db.Anuncios.Include(a => a.Marca).Include(a => a.Modelo)
            select m;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Marcas))
    query = query.Where(m => m.Marca.MarcaNome == Marcas);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Modelos))
    query = query.Where(m => m.Modelo.ModeloNome == Modelos);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(EstadoProdutoTipo))
    query = query.Where(m => m.EstadoProduto.EstadoProdutoTipo == EstadosProdutos);
```

The end result will still by an `IQueryable<T>` for whatever m is, but since the where clauses won't get added until it's actually called. This can be done in the query syntax you've used but it gets very ugly and complicated. This looks a little cleaner and is easier to maintain IMO.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply Joel, it does return any of the selections, but the problem is that it returns results for them individually, i want them to stack togheter like this: first dll has value "Marcas" = A  and second dll has the value "Modelos"=B, so the result must have Marca A and Modelo B  (Marca means Maker and modelo means model, by the way), so OR's aint gona solve it the way I like to.

Comment: @Ricardo_Rodrigues: So if I understand you correctly, if you select only 1 dropdown you want it to return that dropdown but if you select 2 dropdowns you want it to return only if it's both. And you want to be able to select any set of the 3 in any order.